# Good places to visit Dead Sea on the Israeli side

Tags: israel, dead-sea

I have never been to Dead Sea, and I'm planning to visit there during an Israel trip I'm planning.

Are there any specific "spots" that are popular entry points to the sea? I'm a good swimmer but I'm a bit worried about the safety. What are the popular entry points from the Israel end to get your body covered in the mud and to go into the sea?

(I know it is not a big "sea" per se, but here in my county we have popular beaches. Dead Sea probably have too).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's not just not a "sea" it's really not a swimmable anything.  In fact you're more likely to be [just sitting in it](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Dead_sea_newspaper.jpg) then swimming.  The organized beaches around [Ein Bokek](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ein_Bokek) and [Neve Zohar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neve_Zohar) have very shallow water not really suitable for anything but sitting.

Most if not all beaches are organized near hotels so if you're looking for information hotels or small shop owners will be happy to provide it.

Comment: Thanks! Neve Zohar looks really good, specially the Neve Zohar is the lowest village in the world!